# Java - Search for a specific property whilst iterating through a list of objects

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am struggling to find a relevant answer to solve my problem. I have an array list:

```
List<Teacher> teacherList = new ArrayList<Teacher>(11);
```

The teacher class has a name property. I want to scan through the list of teachers, and find out if there is a name that matches the name of the user input.

So for example,

```
Scanner teacherNameScanner = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("What is the teachers name");
teacherName = teacherNameScanner.nextLine();

/* Here I want to scan through the teacherList and see whether the name entered
matches the name of any of the teachers. If it does not match I want to tell the
user to enter a correct name */
```

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your use case, is the name case sensitive? Also you might want to consider trimming spaces. Then create a Set nameSet where you can do a get on existing names which is a O(1) operation. Again there are many solutions for this, unless you describe the exact use case like whether you want to identify a teacher with name or id(usually its an id) its kind of hard to come up with the right solution. But with what you described HashSet should do.

```
Set<String> nameSet = new HashSet<String>();

if (nameSet.contains(teacherName))
   do what you want
else
   other case
```

Comment: Nice, hadn't considered a Set. If you're only looking to go through it once, probably better to iterate through and check, that said, this kills iteration if you're doing it repeatedly.

Comment: Need to populate it though, `new HashSet<Teacher>(teacherList)` or something like that.

Comment: yes, I just wanted to give pseudo code and idea.

Answer (score 1):

In **Java8** you can use streams:

```
public static Teacher findByName(Collection<Teacher> teachers, String name) {
    return teachers.stream().filter(teacher -> teacher.getName().equals(name)).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Additionally, in case you have many different objects (not only `Teacher`) or you want to find it by different properties (not only by `name`), you could build an utility class, to ecapsulate this logic in it:

```
public final class FindUtils {
    public static <T> T findByProperty(Collection<T> col, Predicate<T> filter) {
        return col.stream().filter(filter).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
}

public final class TeacherUtils {
    public static Teacher findByName(Collection<Teacher> teachers, String name) {
        return FindUtils.findByProperty(teachers, teacher -> teacher.getName().equals(name));
    }

    public static Teacher findByAge(Collection<Teacher> teachers, int age) {
        return FindUtils.findByProperty(teachers, teacher -> teacher.getAge() == age);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To scan the `teacherList` and find if there is match of the entered teacher's name (`teacherName`) one of the following methods can be used. Note each method takes the `teacherList` and the `enteredName` as arguments and returns a `boolean` true or false - depending upon if a match is found.

There are three methods and each performs differently. Note the third construct C - this uses different approach than the first two - A and B.

Method A:

Iterate the `teacherList` using a for-loop and find if there is a teacher with matching name:

```
for (Teacher teacher : teacherList) {
    if (teacher.getName().equals(enteredName)) {
        // a match is found
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

Method B:

This has the same functionality as that of method A, but uses different code construct - streams and lambdas:

```
boolean enteredTeacherExists =  teacherList.stream()
                                           .anyMatch(teacher -> teacher.getName().equals(enteredName));
```

The syntax `teacher -> teacher.getName().equals(enteredName)` is a lambda expression of type `Predicate<Teacher>`.

Method C:

This method uses a different approach. Instead of testing for the teacher's name - a teacher object is constructed using the entered name and the object is used for finding a match.

Create a teacher from the name entered and test if it exists in the list.

```
Teacher enteredTeacher = new Teacher(enteredName);
boolean enteredTeacherExists = teacherList.contains(enteredTeacher);
```

In case the teacher with the same name exists in the list the value returned will be true, otherwise a false.

Note the `Teacher` class (see definition below) has an `java.lang.Object` class's overridden `equals()` method. This method specifies the criteria for equality of two teacher objects - if their names are equal then the teacher objects are considered equal. This allows the usage of equals `List`'s `contains` method.

**The Code:**

Teacher.java:

```
public class Teacher {

    private String name;

    public Teacher(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    /* This returns a string representation of the teacher - the name. */
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if ((other != null) && (other instanceof Teacher)) {
            Teacher otherTeacher = (Teacher) other;
            if (otherTeacher.getName().equals(this.name)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

TeacherTester.java

```
public class TeacherTester {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        // Create some teachers
        Teacher teacher1 = new Teacher("first");
        Teacher teacher2 = new Teacher("second");
        Teacher teacher3 = new Teacher("third");
        List<Teacher> teacherList = Arrays.asList(teacher1, teacher2, teacher3);

        System.out.println("Teachers: " + teacherList);

        // Look for teacher - using method A
        String enteredName = "ninth";
        System.out.println("A. Found " + enteredName + " : " + findTeacherA(teacherList, enteredName));
        enteredName = "first";
        System.out.println("A. Found " + enteredName + " : " + findTeacherA(teacherList, enteredName));

        // Look for teacher - using method B
        enteredName = "ninth";
        System.out.println("B. Found " + enteredName + " : " + findTeacherB(teacherList, enteredName));
        enteredName = "second";
        System.out.println("B. Found " + enteredName + " : " + findTeacherB(teacherList, enteredName));

        // Look for teacher - using method C
        enteredName = "third";
        System.out.println("C. Found " + enteredName + " : " + findTeacherC(teacherList, enteredName));
        enteredName = "ninth";
        System.out.println("C. Found " + enteredName + " : " + findTeacherC(teacherList, enteredName));     

    }

    private static boolean findTeacherA(List<Teacher> teacherList, String enteredName) {

        for (Teacher teacher : teacherList) {

            if (teacher.getName().equals(enteredName)) {
                // a match is found
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static boolean findTeacherB(List<Teacher> teacherList, String enteredName) {

        return teacherList.stream()
                            .anyMatch(teacher -> teacher.getName().equals(enteredName));
    }

    private static boolean findTeacherC(List<Teacher> teacherList, String enteredName) {

        Teacher enteredTeacher = new Teacher(enteredName);
        return teacherList.contains(enteredTeacher);
    }
}
```

The Output:

```
Teachers: [first, second, third]
A. Found ninth : false
A. Found first : true
B. Found ninth : false
B. Found second : true
C. Found third : true
C. Found ninth : false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 or above you can use:

```
teacherList.stream().anyMatch(teacher -> teacher.getName().equals(name));
```

where name is the name you are searching for.

Answer (score -1):

A `for each` is just what the doctor ordered (unless you have some fancy ordering you can do a more efficient search with).

```
private Teacher findTheTeacher(ArrayList<Teacher> teacherList, String teacherName) {

    for (Teacher teacher : teacherList) {
        if (teacher.name.equals(teacherName)) {
            return teacher;
        }
    }
    return null; // or something like this
}
```